# Persistent checkbox state in Meteor when switching among Routes

Tags: meteor, checkbox, flow-router

**Question: In a single page app, does Meteor maintain state of Checkbox when user goes from one page to another?**

I am trying to develop a 'Select books to read' app in Meteor where on homepage, user can choose from multiple books to add to his reading list. The chosen books show up on the My Reading List page.
I have set up routing system with Flow Router.

```js
// routes.js

    FlowRouter.route('/', {
        name: 'bookList',
        action: function() {
            BlazeLayout.render("mainLayout", {content: "bookList"});
        }
    });
    FlowRouter.route('/myReadingList', {
        name: 'myReadingList',
        action: function() {
            BlazeLayout.render("mainLayout", {content: "myReadingList"});
        }
    });


// bookList.js Helpers for bookList template

    Template.bookList.helpers({
          'books': function() {
            return books.find();
          }
    });
    
    Template.bookList.events({
              'change .item': function(event) {
                  var temp = false;
                  Session.set("temp", event.target.checked);

                  if (Session.get("temp")) {
                      myReadingList.insert({
                          userid: Meteor.userId(),
                          bookName: this.bookName
                      });
                  } else {
                      var bookName = this.bookName;
                      Meteor.call('removebook', bookName); // remove unselected                                                              // books from list
                    }

    });

// myReadingList.js Helpers for second page
      
      Template.myReadlingList.helpers({
      'selectedBooks':function(){
       return selectedBooks.find();    
      }
    )};
```

```html
<!-- bookList.html : Homepage:bookList Template -->

    {{#each books}}
       <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox" class="item"> {{bookName}}
       </ul>
     {{/each}}


<!-- myReadingList.html: Second Page:myReadingList Template -->

    {{#each selectedBooks}}
      <ul>
        <li>{{ name }}li>
      </ul>
    {{/each}}
```

Problem: Everything works as expected. I am able to choose books on first page. And the selected books show up on the second page. But when I go back to the first page to add more books or review selected books, all the checkboxes are fresh as new.

- Is this normal in Meteor or am I missing something?
- If this is normal, how can I make the checkbox state persist when switching back and forth between page 1 and 2?

Comment: This is normal behavior. You're switching routes and that means the DOM is getting rebuilt when you reload a template (i.e. navigate back into a previous route). If you only need to save the state for the current *session* then you can just use a `Session` variable to do so. If you want to be able to save the state between multiple logins and across machines then you'll want to keep that state in a collection.

Comment: Thanks @Michel. That clears my confusion.

Comment: Or you could hide the templates you don't need and avoid destorying them to keep state. But I'm guessing you want to do what @MichelFloyd suggested.

Comment: Right, show/hide might be good enough in a single-page site.

Comment: Right! I never thought show/hide div could do the trick. But now I'm thinking cant show/hide div be substituted for routing system. What would be the pros and cons of using show/hide and routing? @EliezerSteinbock

Comment: Pros are it can be faster since you don't need rebuild templates. You're basically caching them. Cons are that your app will probably turn into a mess and potentially take up too much memory. I think there was a meteorhacks solution using flowrouter that caches templates. Forgotten what it's called